# How to describe an unsmooth hill?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a really quick and dumb question here. I need to describe a distribution. I have difficulty with explaining an unsmooth hill. If you see the picture, after the peak there is a hill but it doesn't go straight down. There is a flat place, but I don't know how to explain this flat place. I thought this can be explained as bump, but it is not accurate to explain as bump.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: How accurate do you expect to get?  Why do you think a "bump" is not accurate?  if you rotated the graph such that the downslope was horizontal and drove your car over it, you'd definitely say there was a bump in the road.   perhaps you could say that there is an intermediate ledge on the downslope.

Comment: If it were a little rougher it would be "jagged".

Comment: It's a hill with a hillside hill. ;-)

Comment: It depends on the scale. If the bump is small (say up to  a meter) then it could be a ledge.   Depending on location, it could be a berm. Please give some indication of size in your diagram.

Answer (score 4):

After reaching a peak, the curve goes halfway down only to form **a secondary plateau** (mentioned in Edwin Ashworth's comment) before it moves down again.

> plateau - (noun)  "a region of little or no change in a graphic representation" [Meriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plateau)

Answer (score 1):

You could call that flat place a [**ledge**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ledge) on the slope. One definition of "ledge" is "a flat surface that projects from a wall of rock." In your picture, the flat section certainly projects from the rock face above it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just call the "bump" a [*foothill*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foothill). I always thought that foothills were *technically* only at the foot of a mountain, but according to that definition, it can be at the "foot of higher hills".

Edit: I thought there was a mathematical term for that specific kind of curve, though I can't remember what it was.